# Cypress - iframes - Unable to target second field, the test hangs then times out

Tags: testing, iframe, automation, cypress

I'm coming across an issue where once my test card number is typed into the first iframe the test tries to target the 2nd iframe (CVC) & it times out whilst trying to target the element. All info is listed below. Any help to why this is failing is appreciated!

Custom commands used:

```js
    // Make the iframe command return the body contents once it’s loaded
    Cypress.Commands.add("iframe", { prevSubject: "element" }, ($iframe) => {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
       $iframe.on("load", () => {
         resolve($iframe.contents().find("body"));
      });
     });
    });
```

Commands for targeting the card number & CVC for guest users

```js
    // Checkout Add Card New Customer Card Number

    Cypress.Commands.add(
      "addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCardNumber",
      ({ cardNumber, expiry }) => {
      // Card number iFrame
      cy.get("#cardNumber-container > iframe")
         .iframe()
         .find('input[name="number"]')
         .should("be.visible")
         .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "Enter card number")
         .type(cardNumber);
       // Expiry date is not an iframe
      cy.get("[data-cy=expiryDate]").type(expiry);
     }
    );

     // Checkout Add Card New Customer CVC

     Cypress.Commands.add("addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCVC", ({ cvc }) => {
       // CVC iFrame
     cy.get("#cvc-container > iframe")
        .iframe()
        .find('input[name="securityCode"]')
        .should("be.visible")
        .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "•••")
        .type(cvc);
     });
```

This are the 'it' statements from the test:

```js
        it("User adds new AMEX card for payment - Card number", () => {
           cy.addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCardNumber({
               cardNumber: "370000000000002",
               expiry: "0330",
         });
      });
        it("User adds new AMEX card for payment - CVC", () => {
           cy.addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCVC({
               cvc: "7373",
         });
      });
```

Here's a screenshot showing what the test is doing. It successfully finds the card input & fills it in but it fails for the CVC.

[image]

It then times out and the test cannot complete:

[image]

*NOTE* The selector it's trying to find is correct.

[image]

This also works when only trying to target the CVC field in a different scenario where a card number is not needed.

[image]

The code used for this is identical to the command that is having issues.

```
// Select Existing Card Cybersource
  Cypress.Commands.add("selectExistingCardCybersource", ({ cvc }) => {
// CVC iFrame
   cy.get("#cvc-container > iframe")
       .iframe()
       .find('input[name="securityCode"]')
       .should("be.visible")
       .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "•••")
       .type(cvc);
   });
```

Any idea what is going wrong? This is quite a big blocker.

EDITED TO INCLUDE THE FULL HTML.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="sc-bYoBSM efbeJM">
                    <div class="sc-ezbkAF jQjguY">
                        <div class="sc-dJjYzT hFgVEy">Name on card</div><input class="sc-kLwhqv hfTyyh card-name"
                            placeholder="Your name" data-cy="cardName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="sc-ezbkAF jQjguY">
                        <div class="sc-dJjYzT hFgVEy">Card number</div>
                        <div id="cardNumber-container" class="sc-ikJyIC gvVat flex-microform flex-microform-valid">
                            <iframe hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"
                                marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
                                src="https://testflex.cybersource.com/cybersource/assets/microform/0.11.5/iframe.html?keyId=081ZqeqNTRWxPWy3gLgtSt7reOnfdz2l#{&quot;microformId&quot;:&quot;e01efa2c-96b6-43ae-a038-e81de8a9ae17&quot;,&quot;fieldId&quot;:&quot;58666f5e-2c66-4d7a-9dae-a549dd7e8ea6&quot;,&quot;jwt&quot;:&quot;eyJraWQiOiJ6dSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.MtWDbBZfK6YBK6RE9mwBEgZ249jbFgIDrmCjDC4lyAGQRgL3JMBPVsrnj5CNLk3QKamnMF4za25FouGsaAWBEq8MHssNaXLxEspwEM702THodpTQ0-2NZ1nAx5trtx2LvoDjIAUliKHHrgvMcvAQS04IfsWKZwehm9hLmRilnVi6NNq2eyEPLpcbeoQx55cJyKA2lvsWZxDwqVyo5q_LqwqeCrcxvIQzXRbn8_zJXwymROgYKZGgQ-lGoxwns2EJDgVM1kg2f2-SZTza4aoN7SDBVljL-JpsAV_dS9thXLWJ2ov3tgIezMRDPPNDuTwCZDPHY5Ai4kCC2_t_70fM2w&quot;,&quot;microformConfig&quot;:{&quot;styles&quot;:{&quot;input&quot;:{&quot;font-size&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;font-family&quot;:&quot;Roboto, sans-serif&quot;}}},&quot;config&quot;:{&quot;placeholder&quot;:&quot;Enter card number&quot;},&quot;fieldType&quot;:&quot;number&quot;}"
                                style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sc-ezbkAF jQjguY">
                        <div class="sc-dJjYzT hFgVEy">Expiry date*</div><input name="expiryDate"
                            aria-label="Expiry date in format MM YY" autocomplete="cc-exp" id="expiryDate"
                            placeholder="MM/YY" type="tel" data-cy="expiryDate"
                            class="sc-kLwhqv hfTyyh expiry-date null" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="sc-ezbkAF jQjguY">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="sc-dJjYzT hFgVEy">Security code*</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div id="cvc-container" class="sc-jJoQJp ewxrAe flex-microform"><iframe hspace="0"
                                        vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"
                                        marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
                                        src="https://testflex.cybersource.com/cybersource/assets/microform/0.11.5/iframe.html?keyId=081ZqeqNTRWxPWy3gLgtSt7reOnfdz2l#{&quot;microformId&quot;:&quot;e01efa2c-96b6-43ae-a038-e81de8a9ae17&quot;,&quot;fieldId&quot;:&quot;dce7c4ce-d302-47ae-9d0b-f7b2be73dbad&quot;,&quot;jwt&quot;:&quot;eyJraWQiOiJ6dSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.MtWDbBZfK6YBK6RE9mwBEgZ249jbFgIDrmCjDC4lyAGQRgL3JMBPVsrnj5CNLk3QKamnMF4za25FouGsaAWBEq8MHssNaXLxEspwEM702THodpTQ0-2NZ1nAx5trtx2LvoDjIAUliKHHrgvMcvAQS04IfsWKZwehm9hLmRilnVi6NNq2eyEPLpcbeoQx55cJyKA2lvsWZxDwqVyo5q_LqwqeCrcxvIQzXRbn8_zJXwymROgYKZGgQ-lGoxwns2EJDgVM1kg2f2-SZTza4aoN7SDBVljL-JpsAV_dS9thXLWJ2ov3tgIezMRDPPNDuTwCZDPHY5Ai4kCC2_t_70fM2w&quot;,&quot;microformConfig&quot;:{&quot;styles&quot;:{&quot;input&quot;:{&quot;font-size&quot;:&quot;16px&quot;,&quot;font-family&quot;:&quot;Roboto, sans-serif&quot;}}},&quot;config&quot;:{&quot;placeholder&quot;:&quot;•••&quot;},&quot;fieldType&quot;:&quot;securityCode&quot;}"
                                        style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cvc col-sm-8">The last 3 digits on the back of your Credit or Debit card
                                (Amex 4 digits on the front).</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sc-gWXbKe bZJPUc"><label class="sc-eCImPb caZvFZ checkbox"><input
                                name="saveCreditCard" type="checkbox" class="sc-iqseJM gIJDbg" value="false">
                            <div class="sc-pVTFL imLlDI"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sc-gKclnd dZWWmA">
                                    <polyline points="20 6 9 17 4 12"></polyline>
                                </svg></div>Add this card to my wallet
                        </label></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"><button type="button" data-cy="useExistingCard" class="sc-crHmcD jOSMtb gotoCard link"
                    style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Cancel and return</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-iIUQWv gaphzu">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><button data-cy="payCard" type="submit" id="confirmAndPay"
                class="sc-crHmcD jOSMtb block">Pay Now</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also added .focus() This successfully enters the CVC field but the type command still fails as it times out.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the timeout is occurring at ` cy.get("#cvc-container > iframe")` due to the element not existing in the DOM with the given selector. Are you for certain that selector is correct?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Yes, this selector is correct. This is taken directly from the HTML - <input name="securityCode". I do have a different scenario where entering a card number is not necessary (existing user flow) and I can target the CVC field without any issues and the test completes. The issue lies with trying to enter the CVC directly after the card number for the guest flow.

Comment: I've edited the post to show a new screenshot @jjhelguero

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I haven't worked with iframes much in my company. I'd suggest maybe attaching an assertion after the `cy.get("#cvc-container > iframe")` to see if you can get some more info.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: It might need a `.blur()` after expiry to enable CVC. Also might be useful to see the HTML.

Comment: @Fody I've edited to include the HTML and some extra information. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @BillyBailey How about you add some `delay` with the type command `.type(cvc, {delay: 50})`

Comment: There is possibility that both the iframes are with same name. so when you are interacting with the iframe for CVC its searching for CVC in first iframe, because of there is more than one element with same identifier then first will be picked.

Comment: Thanks, @DilipMeghwal do you know how I could possibly get around this problem? They are named differently: card number - '#cardNumber-container > iframe'  & cvc - '#cvc-container > iframe'.

Comment: try force type - .type(cvc, {force: true})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this by changing the way I approach the CVC field.

Using the below command fixed my problems.

```
// Checkout Add Card New Customer CVC
Cypress.Commands.add("addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCVC", ({ cvc }) => {
  cy.get("#cvc-container > iframe").then(($element) => {
    const $body = $element.contents().find("body");
    let cvcField = cy.wrap($body);
    cvcField = cy.wrap($body);
    cvcField
      .find('input[name="securityCode"]')
      .should("be.visible")
      .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "•••")
      .click()
      .type(cvc);
  });
});
```

Thanks, everyone for your help with this!

Answer (score 1):

@BillBaily Thanks but I was looking for a larger piece of HTML, covering both iframes.

But another suggestion - I have seen on another project that uses **WorldPay** has ***nested*** iframes, so you would need something like

```js
// Checkout Add Card New Customer CVC

Cypress.Commands.add("addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCVC", ({ cvc }) => { // CVC iFrame

  cy.get("#cardNumber-container > iframe")
    .iframe()
    .within(() => {

      cy.get("#cvc-container > iframe")
        .iframe()
        .find('input[name="securityCode"]')
        .should("be.visible")
        .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "•••")
        .type(cvc)
    })
 })
```

But the test where a card number is not needed contradicts this theory, but worth mentioning in case the page structure differs between the two scenarios.

(BTW what payment library is being used?)

---

I just noticed that in the last screenshot the CVC field has indeed got focus, but name and expiry are empty.

This looks like validation may be preventing anything from being typed into the field. You can check that out by manually trying to only enter the CVC.

Try this for the test

```js
it("User adds new AMEX card for payment - CVC", () => {

  cy.addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCardNumber({
    cardNumber: "370000000000002",
    expiry: "0330",
  })

  // May need a name as well

  cy.addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCVC({
    cvc: "7373",
  })
})
```

Or (as a last resort) use `.type(cvc, {force:true})` in `addCardNewCustomerCybersourceCVC`.

Comment: Also worth trying [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#why) `.realType()` as a replacement for all the `.type()` commands, in case some event handler is not being triggered.

Comment: Hey, @Fody sorry for the long reply. I've been away on annual leave. I've edited to include the full HTML that covers both iFrames. We are moving to Cybersource from Adyen. I've tried all the suggested fixes but to no avail.